# Apply different labels depending on a condition

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a filter that applies a label to any mail from a certain sender. I want to apply a *different* label sometimes depending on the content of the message. I currently have it working by duplicating the 2nd filter into the "Doesn't Have" field of the first filter.

Is it possible to set up my filters without having to copy the 2nd condition into the 1st? I want to be able to update this condition without having to copy it to the other filter every time.

Comment: I'm afraid, no, you have to do what you've already worked out. Filters don't offer any sort of "branching" logic.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a different solution to my problem. Instead of splitting the mail into two labels I have one filter applied to both categories while the 2nd filter excludes the lower priority mail. So now I have one label with normal priority mail and one label with both priorities.